# ¿Cómo puede dar permiso a Eclipse para que pueda acceder al mi directorio en Debian / Linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, debian, gcc

He instalado Eclipse IDE (flatpak) en Debian, el problema estriba que al parecer Eclipse no puede acceder a los archivo #include de la herramienta gcc. Como se puede apreciar en la imagen, aparece subrayado en amarillo. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta otra imagen puede observar el mensaje que dice "que el archivo no está o no se tiene acceso a él".

Como dije, creo que el problema es que Eclipse IDE no tiene los permisos por parte del sistema operativo Debian linux para poder acceder a esos archivo, o puedo estar en un error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En general los permisos no dependen del programa sino del usuario que ejecuta el proceso, busca cómo dar permisos a tu usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los permisos no dependen del programa, dependen de quién ejecuta dicho programa. Así que lo que deberías hacer es darte los permisos a ti mismo en el directorio que necesites, que probablemente sea de otro usuario, por tanto deberás añadirle permisos a "otro". Intenta ejecutar, en el directorio que necesitas acceder, la orden `chmod o+rw .`